# ' | ' operator between python set objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Recently while making changes to a python module someone else wrote which does some processing on Pandas dataframe I came across a line of code which looks like this :

`indices_invalid_entries = \
list(set(indices_invalid_entries) | set(list(df[pd.isnull(df[i])].index)))`

where indices_invalid_enteries is initially an empty list.
So basically what we are doing here is checking for Dataframe indexes in certain columns where there is **NULL** values.

Now I know what **set, list, pd.isnull** functions do.

But what can't seem to get is what purpose is the *BITWISE* **OR** operator **|** here. How will Bitwise OR(ing) of objects gonna store Indices of Invalid Enteries?

Can someone explain?
Thanks

Comment: That's the set union operator (overloaded).

Comment: Ok, Got it man, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), the | operator is the **union operator**.

So as you mentioned in you answer,

```
indices_invalid_entries <-- union(indices_invalid_entries,df[pd.isnull(df[i])].index)
```

And the general case:

```
Union = A | B      # where A,b,Union are sets
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always try it out:

```
>>> x = set([1,2,3])
>>> y = set([2,3,4])
>>> x | y
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>>
```